# Quadratic Diophantine equations solver

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is there software that helps list small solutions of the Diophantine equation
$$
x_0^2=1+x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+ x_n^2
$$
where "small" is negotiable, but e.g. we could fix $x_0$ and and ask for the list of all solutions $x_1, \dots, x_n\in\mathbb Z$?

Comment: This is 
$$(x_0-x_1)(x_0+x_1)=x_0^2-x_1^2=1+x_2^2+\cdots +x_n^2,$$
so sort of reduces to factorization.

Comment: @Will, I wish to distinguish $x_j$ and $-x_j$. Please do not bother to write anything in C++; I just want to know whether there is anything already available as part of Mathematica ot other similar package. @Robin, thanks, reducing factorization is helpful idea.

Comment: For $n=2$ you can try http://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM for various values of $x_0$.

Comment:  SquaresR[d, n] gives the number of ways r_d (n) to represent the integer n as a sum of d squares.

PowersRepresentations[n, k, p] gives the distinct representations of the integer n as a sum of k non-negative p\^th integer powers.


EllipticTheta[a,u,q] gives the theta function Subscript[\[CurlyTheta], a](u,q) (a=1,\[Ellipsis],4). 

Comment: note the above are Mathematica commands

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look on this tutorial: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DiophantineReduce.html ? To take different values n < n_max into account, a simple loop could work.

Answer (score 0):

This function in Mathematica  find them all:

```
f[n_] := Reduce[ Total[Table[x[i]^2, {i, 1, n}]] + 1 == x[0]^2 && 
             (Table[x[i], {i, 1, 3}] /. List -> LessEqual), 
              Table[x[i], {i, 0, n}], Integers]
```

Invoke with:

```
f[1], f[3] ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Sympy, in particular at [diop_general_pythagorean](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/diophantine.html#diop-general-pythagorean).